# How can I pass a member function pointer into a function that takes a regular function pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers, member-functions

I have a player class which looks like this (stripped down to what is needed for this problem):

```
class Player
{
    public:
        Player();
        ~Player();

        void kill();
        void death();
        void reset();
};
```

The `kill()`, `death()`, and `reset()` functions look like this:

```
void Player::kill()
{
    void (*dPtr)() = &death;

    Game::idle(dPtr, 48);
}

void Player::death()
{
    reset();
}

void Player::reset()
{
    //resets
}
```

The idle function is a static memeber function of Game, which takes a function pointer and an integer n, and calls the function after n tick. Here is the function, the implementation shouldn't matter:

```
class Game {
    static void idle(void (*)(), int);
};
```

This code gives me the error:

```
ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say '&Player::death' [-fpermissive]
```

So I change the line from

```
    void (*dPtr)() = &death;
```

to

```
    void (Player::*dPtr)() = &Player::death;
```

to solve that issue. But then my call to the idle function is incorrect, as it takes a regular function pointer, and I am passing in a member function pointer, and thus gives me the error:

```
no matching function for call to 'Game::idle(void (Player::*&)(), int)'
```

So my question is:
How can I pass the member function pointer `Player::*dPtr` into the idle function, which takes a `void (*)()` as an argument?

Or is there another way I can solve my previous error which forbids me from taking the address of an unqualified member function to form a pointer to a member function?

Comment: Take a look on `boost::bind` and `boost::function`.

Comment: Use [`std::bind()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), no need for boost in the current standard.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The object returned by `std::bind` is not assignment-compatible with `void (*)()`.

Comment: @zwol Well, so the function `static void idle(void (*)(), int);` needs to be changed. What's the problem?

Comment: Can you change the interface of `idle`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well, it *does* need to be changed, but there's no good way to change it to make it compatible with `std::bind` given other constraints which I deduce to be present here (namely "Game::idle cannot be a template").

Comment: Does a function pointer also contain the information of the object calling it

Comment: @Yaxlat No, it does not.  That's your entire problem in a nutshell.

Comment: Oh right, that was a false assumption then. I will try your answer. It reminds me a lot of python functions, with passing self in as an object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To call a member function through a pointer, you need *two* pointers: the pointer to the function itself, and a pointer to an object to be `this`.  Your `Game::idle` API does not support this usage.  You need to change it so that it passes at least one argument (conventionally of type `void *`) to the callback.  Then you can use the following pattern:

```
struct Player
{
        // ...
        void kill();

        // ...
        static void call_kill(void *self);
};

void Player::call_kill(void *self)
{
    static_cast<Player *>(self)->kill();
}

struct Game
{
    static void idle(void (*)(void *), void *, int);
};

void Game::idle(void (*callback)(void *), void *arg, int ticks)
{
    // ...
    callback(arg);
    // ...
}

void kill_player_delayed(Player *p, int ticks)
{
    Game::idle(Player::call_kill, static_cast<void *>(p), ticks);
}
```

You have to write a static `call_X` method for every instance method `X` you want to call.

---

An alternative approach, which is arguably more C++-idiomatic and flexible, and involves less explicitly written-out code, but has higher runtime costs (three indirect function calls and a heap allocate-free cycle per invocation, instead of a single indirect function call), is to have `Game::idle` take an object of a particular class, with a virtual callback method.  That class is then given a template subclass that can call anything that implements `operator()`, such as the result of `std::bind`.

```
struct Runnable { virtual ~Runnable(); virtual void invoke() = 0; };

template <typename T> struct TRunnable : Runnable {
    TRunnable(T target) : target(target) {}
    void invoke() { target(); }
private:
    T target;
};
template <typename T> TRunnable<T>* make_Runnable(T obj)
{ return new TRunnable<T>(obj); }

struct Game
{
    static void idle(Runnable *, int);
};

void Game::idle(Runnable *r, int ticks)
{
    // ...
    r->invoke();
    delete r;
    // ...
}

struct Player
{
    // ...
    void kill();
    // ...
};

void kill_player_delayed(Player *p, int ticks)
{
    Game::idle(make_Runnable(std::bind(&Player::kill, p)), ticks);
}
```

You cannot make `Game::idle` take the result of `std::bind` directly because that object's type is unspecified (and varies depending on how you call `std::bind`), so it can only be used as an argument to a *template* function call.  A virtual method call to an adapter class is the only way to keep `Game::idle` compiled out-of-line and still let it use bound-call objects.

In either approach, beware object lifetime issues.  In particular, if `Game::idle` does not call its callback *before returning*, you need to
make sure that *both* the original object, and (in the second approach)
the object returned by `make_Runnable` survive until the callback fires.  This is why `make_Runnable` uses `new`.

Comment: I don't fully understand your first approach. What is the kill_player_delayed function? I'm assuming that refers to what I put as the kill function, and kill() in your refers to my death()?

Comment: @Yaxlat My apologies, I misread your original example.  I thought you had not shown the complete function that calls `Game::idle`, and both `kill` and `death` were things that might need to get called via `Game::idle`.  So I made up `kill_player_delayed` to be the thing that calls `Game::idle`.

Comment: This is a really good approach... so good in fact, that the Standard library already contains it, under the name `std::function`!  (Reinventing it is perhaps not so good)

Comment: @BenVoigt Sadly, nearly all my C++ experience has been with dusty-deck codebases that don't even get to use the C++98 standard library, let alone C++11, so I only have a vague idea of what-all's in there.  Post another answer using `std::function` and I'll upvote it ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Another answer mentions that you need two pointers. However C++ already comes with containers for doing just this, so it would make your code a lot simpler to use those.  (In C++03, some of the `std::` items below were `std::tr1::`).

Sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct Game 
{ 
    static void idle( std::function<void()> func, int x )
        { std::cout << "x = " << x << "\n"; func(); }
};

struct Player
{
     void death() { std::cout << "player.death\n"; }
     void kill() { Game::idle( std::bind(&Player::death, this), 48 ); }
};

int main()
{
    Player p;
    p.kill();
}
```

---

Lifetime note: `std::bind` binds by value. Using `*this` means a copy of the `Player` is made and stored in the `std::function` object, copied around with it as necessary.

Using `this` means the function object stores a pointer, so if you actually store the function object in `Game::idle` you must take care that this `Player` is not destroyed before removing this function object  from `Game::idle`'s list.

Comment: Can you say a little about lifetime issues with this approach?  Specifically, suppose `Game::idle` puts its argument on a queue to be executed "later", well after both it and `Player::kill` returns. Obviously the Player object has to survive till then. Is it safe to treat `std::function` and the unspecified object returned by `std::bind` as value types, lifetime irrelevant? Is there any way to make a `std::function` hold onto a `shared_ptr` to some or all of the arguments passed to `std::bind`?

Comment: @zwol edited post to mention lifetime issues.  It is possible to use `shared_ptr` with `bind`, however this only works if your original object is also managed by `shared_ptr` of course.

Comment: [Sample code using delayed idle and shared_ptr](http://ideone.com/ba9Y7Y) .  To enforce `Player` being created under `shared_ptr` you could have private constructor and friend `Game`, and give `Game` a factory function.

Answer (score 1):

Because I really don't like the answer that casts `void*`'s to other objects (almost never necessary in C++!) and nobody has posted an answer using the suggestions in the comments I'm going to suggest this.

Use a templated type for your callback!

Like this:

```
class Game{
    template<typename Func>
    static void idle(Func &&func, int i){
        // game stuff
        func();
        // other game stuff
    }
};
```

Then you don't lose all of your type safety (casting `void*`) and it should be the fastest solution.

---

Also, where you are assigning a function pointer, you can change the code to be far more readable in this case:

```
void Player::kill(){
    Game::idle([this](){this->death();}, 48);
}
```

Which is far nicer than having to write the correct function pointer type.

Comment: This is great as long as the callback doesn't have to be saved somewhere for later use.  If it does, then `std::function<void ()>` is a better solution.  Both lambdas and `std::bind` results can convert to `std::function`.

Comment: @BenVoigt I always avoid using `virtual` functions or `std::function` in any high-performance programming (such as game programming) because of the slowdown of the indirection. But if I needed to store the callback, you're absolutely right and reinventing the wheel wouldn't be useful to anyone!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that simply because pointer to [static] function is a single pointer sizeof `void*`. In contrary member function need more information, e.g. two pointers: one for `this` and another one for the function itself so member function pointer has `sizeof > sizeof(void*)`.

Therefore you have two options:

1. to change signature of your idle() to this `void idle(void (*)(), void*, int);` so you will be able to pass `this` somehow.
2. Or make static variable that will hold `this` pointer. But that assumes that only one `death()` can be at idle queue at any given moment of time.

1) is what people do usually in such cases.

Comment: Yes I ended up doing 1) thanks to zwol's suggestion. I incorrectly assumed c++ function pointers included a pointer to the object the belong to when they are member functions.